what is the syntax to use groupby by column index rather than column name?
here i have a code snip that creates a groupby object with the count of duplicates.
gbo = data2.groupby("1").count()
display(gbo)

this works perfectly because the column names are indexes but will not work if the columns do not have a numeric index. i want to call the column by index number for the groupby function and need the correct simple syntax. this is the output of the above code and has the correct result.
    0   2   3   4   5   
1                                               
Alph    7   6   5   4   
Beta    351 350 337 303 
Gamma   234 233 230 226 
Delt    2   1   0   0   

the issue is that if the columns were designated as Col1, Col2, Col3.. ect,. how do i access Col1 as column index0 or column 2 as column index1. i cant seem to find the proper syntax
here is an example code:
mydat = [{"a":"gnome", "b": "home", "c": "trail", "d" : np.nan},
        {"a": "goblin", "b": "fort", "c": "tower", "d" : "open"}, 
        {"a": "tree", "b": "forest", "c": np.nan, "d" : np.nan},
        {"a": "tree", "b": "grove", "c": np.nan, "d" : np.nan},
        {"a": "gnome", "b": "hill", "c": "shade", "d" : "sleep"}]

    a   b   c   d
0   gnome   home    trail   NaN
1   goblin  fort    tower   open
2   tree    forest  NaN NaN
3   tree    grove   NaN NaN
4   gnome   hill    shade   sleep

www = mydf.groupby("a").count()
display(www)

    b   c   d
a           
gnome   2   2   1
goblin  1   1   1
tree    2   0   0

so i get a count of values per level. i want to do the same by calling the index of the column instead of the "a" label. if it possible in one line or do i need to rename the column by index ??

Something like this?
group_column = data2.iloc[:, 0] to select columns.
gbo = data2.groupby(group_column).count()

i believe adamj754 clarified the syntax by using the level attribute.

You can specify the index as such, indicating the level without quotations will specify the index.
gbo = data2.groupby(level=1).count()
display(gbo)

EDIT:
After seeing the example code here is a work around for your example code.
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

mydat = [{"a":"gnome", "b": "home", "c": "trail", "d" : np.nan},
        {"a": "goblin", "b": "fort", "c": "tower", "d" : "open"}, 
        {"a": "tree", "b": "forest", "c": np.nan, "d" : np.nan},
        {"a": "tree", "b": "grove", "c": np.nan, "d" : np.nan},
        {"a": "gnome", "b": "hill", "c": "shade", "d" : "sleep"}]
mydf = pd.DataFrame(data=mydat)
www = mydf.groupby(mydf.columns[0]).count()
print(www)

mydf.columns[0] finds the name of the column for your groupby

great, thank you sir. this question has been asked all over google with the answer escaping the obvious. this is the the solution.

i spoke prematurely. it looks like i recieved an error : ValueError: level > 0 or level < -1 only valid with MultiIndex

Can you post your df code and I can see what I can do?

i edited my post with an example code.

i don't think there is a way. the question is asked often but it seems there is not attribute to access columns by index value.

www = mydf.groupby(mydf.columns[0]).count().. yes this worked perfectly!!
